# Using selenium for triggering jobs in putty or Tivoli work scheduler

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, putty, tivoli-work-scheduler

Can we use selenium to trigger batch jobs in putty or TWS. If yes, can anyone please give me some direction over which library or plug in to use .

Answer (score 0):

If I not misunderstand your final goal is to execute shell command on linux, if so, you can see this library: [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and [code example](https://www.journaldev.com/246/jsch-example-java-ssh-unix-server)